# lightning:dataTable action column is not rendering properly

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning-design-system, lightning-datatable

I have added a lightning:dataTable within  like this

```
<lightning:card title="My Table" iconName="standard:contact">
     <p class="slds-p-horizontal_small">
            <lightning:datatable
                  aura:id="sparesTable"
                  columns="{! v.columns }"
                  data="{!v.stipulationsSpares}"
                  keyField="Id"
                  hideCheckboxColumn="true"
                  showRowNumberColumn="false"
              />
     </p>
 </lightning:card>
```

I am creating columns like this in the controller

```
var actions = [
            { label: 'Show details', name: 'show_details' },
            { label: 'Delete', name: 'delete' }
        ];

component.set('v.columns', [
    {label: 'Start Date', fieldName: 'Start_Date__c',type: 'date'},
    {label: 'End Date', fieldName: 'End_Date__c', type: 'date'},        
   { type: 'action', typeAttributes: { rowActions: actions } } 
]);
```

When I click on the down arrow on the action column the dropdown menu of actions appears but I need to scroll down to view

[image]

This looks bad particularly if there is just one row in the table . Its hard for users to understand that a menu is there if they don't scroll.

Is there any way this menu gets visible without scrolling ?

Answer (score 1):

Just specify a minimum height for the table, and it should work fine:

## CSS

```
.THIS .min-height {
    display: inline-block;
    min-height: 200px;
}
```

## CODE

```
<lightning:card title="My Table" iconName="standard:contact">
    <p class="slds-p-horizontal_small">
        <lightning:datatable
                             class="min-height"
                             aura:id="sparesTable"
                             columns="{! v.columns }"
                             data="{!v.stipulationSpares}"
                             keyField="id"
                             hideCheckboxColumn="true"
                             showRowNumberColumn="false"
                             />
    </p>
</lightning:card>
```

Comment: Still same issue

Answer (score 0):

`lightning:datatable` is still buggy with the menus as of v43.

I've found this combination to work okay. First you specify a relative height then you override this class provided by SLDS.

```
.THIS .table-container {
  height: 59vh;
}
.THIS div.slds-scrollable_y {
  height: 100% !important;
}
```

Where your component looks like

```
<div class="table-container">
  <lightning:datatable... />
</div>
```